# Need Help Writing Equations For These Equations? Pre Calc 12

Tags: calculus

Need Help Writing Equations For These Equations? Pre Calc 12

1) Vertical Asypmptotes at x=1/4, x intercept of x=0, and a discontinous point at (5,5/19)

2) Y-Intercept at -5, no x-intercepts, discontinous points at (-1,-5) and (3,-5)

Comment: Woops: "equations for these equations"? Do you mean you need to create functions meeting the criteria?

Comment: It says write the equation of a possibl e rational function withe the following charestics explain your reasoing

Comment: Got it...What have you figured out, so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do some trouble-shooting with respect to the first question:

$(1)$ For the first, we need that it intersects the $x-axis$ (i.e. y = 0) when $x = 0$. So when $x = 0 \implies y = 0$: the function must intersect the origin. You need to do a little trial-and-error: how would a rational function have a vertical asymptote at $x = 1/4$? Often case, this is when the denominator evaluates to $0$ when $x = a$, where $x = a$ is a vertical asymptote.  So: try $$y = \dfrac x{4x-1}$$

Note: $4x - 1 = 0 \iff x = 1/4$. Note that the point $x = 0 \implies y = 0$, which  satisfies the y-intercept at $x = 0$.

Now, how can we make the function discontinuous at $\left(5, \frac 5{19}\right)$?

---

$(2)$: Hint...Consider the equation of the horizontal line $y = -5$; it certainly intersects the y-axis when $x = 0$ and figure out how you can modify /define the function to make it discontinuous when $x = -1, x = 3$: recall, you can define a function to be a *piece-wise" function: E.g., figure out the x-values that will make the second function discontinuous at the required points:

$$y = \begin{cases} 11 & \text{when}\;\;x = a \;\text{or}\;x = b \\ \\
-5 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Why don't you work at this, and work some more on $(1)$, and comment below with any progress report.

Comment: Nice guidance! +1

Comment: super help full but  I don't know how to complete it ? please finish

Comment: I understand the first concept but not sure how to complete can you show me ? :)

Comment: Gary, I've done most of the work already. Right now, the first function is continuous at $(5, 5/19)$. What little qualification can you make in the function definition (e.g. piecewise function) to make it $y \neq 5/19$ when $x = 5$?

Comment: Do you make it continuos at x=5 I'am really confused at this concept for math if you could help me out that be great.